# using gsub to find all values that are NOT equal in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use gsub to change values in an Igraph vertex variable to colors before I plot a network graph.
The issue is that my graph has 3 values that I care about, and many others that I'd just like to group as "other" and assign 1 color to.

For example, if I had data that looks like this:

```
Name........Value  
A............1  
B............2  
C............3  
D............4  
E............5
```

and I had code like this:

```
V(g)$color=V(g)$value #assign the "Value" attribute as the vertex color  
V(g)$color=gsub("1","red",V(g)$color) #1 will be red  
V(g)$color=gsub("2","blue",V(g)$color) #2 will be blue  
V(g)$color=gsub("3", "yellow", V(DMedge)$color) #3 is yellow
```

What line of code could I add to make 4 and 5 into some other color, (green for example)? Thanks so much for any help you might have!

Comment: I'd start by assigning that color to the entire vector `V(g)$color` and then use `V(g)$value` with `ifelse` or some other form of lookup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid `sub` (this is not about matching patterns) and do:

```
my.colors <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green")
V(g)$color <- my.colors[match(V(g)$value, c(1, 2, 3), nomatch = 4)]
```

Comment: I think this approach is the most extendable (beyond 3-4 levels), fastest, and generalizable to new situations.

Comment: np. please consider accepting the answer then (or any other of your choice.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that after you have made the initial substitutions, the only numbers left are the ones you want to be one uniform color, you can use a `regex` to match all contiguous digits and put the same color for them.

```
V(g)$color=gsub("\\d+", "green",V(g)$color)
```

See [this page](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php) for `gsub` regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this suffices for what you want to do:

```
x <- c("1","2","3","4")
gsub("4|5", "green", x) 
[1] "1"     "2"     "3"     "green" "green"
```

Or this

```
 gsub("[^1-3]", "green", x) 
[1] "1"     "2"     "3"     "green" "green"
```

However as pointed out in other answers **it looks like a better idea to set up a lookup table** mapping numbers to colors and use `match` to determine the color.